# Involve ajax in autocomplete

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I have this auto complete option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {

        $("#tags").autocomplete(["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "pearl"], {
            width: 320,
            max: 4,
            highlight: false,
            multiple: true,
            multipleSeparator: " ",
            scroll: true,
            scrollHeight: 300
        });
    });
    </script>

    <body> <p>
        <label>Tags (local):</label>
        <input type="text" id='tags' />
    </p>
</body>
```

But I would like to get this array from an action method: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "pearl"]. For example from action "QuickSearch" in controller "Search".

So something like this:

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> list = test();
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the remote documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: What autocomplete plugin are you using?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete this one. But their remote completion is using php, and not asp.net. They echo the result. I would like to use JSON.

Comment: Are you sure that's the one you are using? jQueryUI's autocomplete does not take arguments `multiple` or `highlight`

Comment: I'm not sure... I have totally no idea how to get the data from an action list into my autocomplete option... I am starting to get a bit desperated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put the URL to the action method that returns the datasource as the "source" parameter to the autocomplete function.  From the documentation:

A data source can be:

- an Array with local data
- a String,specifying a URL
- a Callback

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: "URL to your method"
        width: 320,
        max: 4,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: " ",
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 300
    });
});
</script>
```

You need to add a source property to the options object that is passed in, and that source can be an array, a callback, or in your case a URL to a method.

Where the relative URL from the root would be "Search/QuickSearch"

Comment: I have tried this, and put a breakpoint in the QuickSearch action, but it is not getting there...